# Javascript Array includes returning false after JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am creating an array in javascript inserting an element into it and then checking for its existence using `includes`. It returns true.
But when I am converting the array into a string using `JSON.stringify` and then converting back to the array using `JSON.parse` and then testing for the same, it returns false.

This is baffling me.

```js
var test_object = {'id': 1, 'name': 'Test'};
var initial = [];

initial.push(test_object);
console.log(initial.includes(test_object));

var later = JSON.stringify(initial);
later = JSON.parse(later);
console.log(later.includes(test_object));
```

Here is a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/boxirejudu/edit?js,console) for the same.

Comment: Your code should be here. The answer is that objects are compared by identity, not value/structure.

Comment: the answer is this {} == {} //false
you have to check if the 2 objects have same structure

Comment: Even though `later` and `test_object` seem the same, they are actually two separate objects with separate memory addresses. When you do `stringify -> parse` the object is considered an entirely new object with a separate address. `array.includes` compares the elements by their value for value types, and by reference for complex types, such as objects.

Comment: You are losing the reference.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `json.parse` you are returning a new object. Objects are compared by identity rather than value when using `includes`, which is why it returns false. If you wanted to you could modify the `includes` prototype (though I don't recommend doing this) to do a deeper object comparison

```
Array.prototype.includes = function(searchElement /*, fromIndex*/) {
    'use strict';
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.includes called on null or undefined');
    }

    var O = Object(this);
    var len = parseInt(O.length, 10) || 0;
    if (len === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    var n = parseInt(arguments[1], 10) || 0;
    var k;
    if (n >= 0) {
      k = n;
    } else {
      k = len + n;
      if (k < 0) {k = 0;}
    }
    var currentElement;
    while (k < len) {
       currentElement = O[k];
       if (JSON.stringify(searchElement) === JSON.stringify(currentElement) || searchElement === currentElement ||
         (searchElement !== searchElement && currentElement !== currentElement)) { // NaN !== NaN
        return true;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Note that this code is based on the [`Array.prototype.includes` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Answer (score 0):

As winhowes states includes checks by identity not value.

you can try this:

```
if (!Array.prototype.includesCallback) {
    Array.prototype.includesCallback = function(predicate) {
        'use strict';
        if (this == null) {
            throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.includeCallback called on null or undefined');
        }
        if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
            throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
        }
            var list = Object(this);
            var length = list.length >>> 0;
            var thisArg = arguments[1];
            var value;

            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            value = list[i];
            if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    };
}
```

which will let you utilize a function to perform the comparasin

```
later.includesCallback (
    function(item) {
        return item.id === test_object.id;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.prototype.includesEquivalent = function (obj) {
 for (var o in this) {
   for (var p in this[o]) {
  if (this[o][p] !== obj[p]) {
    return false;
  }
   }
 }
 
 return true;
}

var test_object = {'id': 1, 'name': 'Test'};
var initial = [];

initial.push(test_object);
console.log(initial.includes(test_object));

var later = JSON.stringify(initial);
later = JSON.parse(later);

console.log(later.includesEquivalent(test_object));
```